# Swift UITableView: How to Load data from JSON

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I am beginner in Swift and would like some help for my first application.I hope that I can explain it well. I am developing and app which is loading information from a JSON File. Does someone of you know how can I populate this information into a UI Table View Cells. I have developed 3 view controllers, in the first one I have a button, which the user has to press and the 2nd Tableview controller will be opened. I have watched tutorials how to populate it but it seems that it doesn't work. The 3rd one is the Table View Cells.let me show you:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var Bar: UIToolbar!
var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
let ImageList = ["",""]
var TitleList = ["",""]
let DescriptionList = ["",""]
```

I have to display in the cells Image, Title and Description.
here is the JSON File:

```
 {
 “fruits” : [
 {
 “Name” : “Fruit1”,
 “Picture”:”http://www.starpropertiesindia.com/blog/wp-   content/uploads/2016/08/kochi1.jpg”,
“Description”:””,
},

  {
 “Name” : “Fruit2”,
 “Picture”:”http://www.starpropertiesindia.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/kochi1.jpg”,
 “Description”:””,

},
```

I would be very thankful if someone advice me how to continue..

Prepare for segue in new view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var CellDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var CellImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var CellTitle: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
```

Comment: I have tried many things, but I am not sure shall I show them because, it seems that they are wrong

Comment: Can you use third party libraries?

Comment: Great. Please add EVReflection in your project and i am helping you the whole path. ok?

Comment: https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection

Comment: Super, but what is  EVReflection and how can I add it?

Comment: See the link. Install the pod.the link has instruction

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at SwiftyJSON as @Dakata said. It's the easiest way to read the JSON in your case. If you use CocoaPods, it's very easy to implement: https://cocoapods.org/?q=swiftyjson

Comment: Can I use in stead of  EVReflection swifty json?

Comment: I have no problem if Dakata show me some code. @Jordi

Comment: Do you have an email. It will be easier I can Show you the whole project and what I have done?

Comment: do you parse the json using swiftyJson? Show me the code.

Comment: I can send you the whole project it will be easier

Comment: you don't have my email address :) how it will?

Comment: yes, I do not have it. That is why I asked do you have an email address where I can send it or you prefer other services?

Comment: If you can upload it in github , it will be very smart :)

Comment: I do not have an account, do you have skype?

Comment: @Dakata have you got the answer you wanted?

Comment: no I haven't :( I do not know what else should I provide you because the rest in my code is wrong, it is useless to show it here

Comment: @Dakata No, you should show it. Your problem can be solved **much** easier if you show your code and explain what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, don't use multiple arrays for the data source. They are quite error-prone because you are responsible to keep the number of items in sync.

- Since Swift is an object-oriented language use a custom struct as model

  ```
  struct Fruit {
    let name : String
    let imageURL : NSURL
    let description : String
  }
  ```
- Declare an empty Swift array of `Fruit` as data source array. Basically use **always** Swift native collection types (rather than `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`) because they contain the type information.

  ```
  var fruits = [Fruit]()
  ```
- Create a function to parse the JSON and reload the table view. The code assumes that the JSON file is named `jsonFile.json` and is located in the application bundle. Further it uses the `SwiftyJSON` library.

  ```
  func parseFruits() {
    guard let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("jsonFile", withExtension: "json"), jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {
      print("Error finding JSON File")
      return
    }

    let jsonObject = JSON(data: jsonData)

    let fruitArray = jsonObject["fruits"].arrayValue
    for aFruit in fruitArray {
      let name = aFruit["Name"].stringValue
      let imageURL = aFruit["Picture"].stringValue
      let description = aFruit["Description"].stringValue

      let fruit = Fruit(name: name, imageURL: NSURL(string:imageURL)!, description:description)
      fruits.append(fruit)
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```
- in `viewWillAppear` call the parse function

  ```
  override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    parseFruits()
  }
  ```
- These are the table view data source delegate methods assuming the identifier of the cell is `Cell` and the style of the cell is `Right Detail` or `Subtitle`

  ```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruits.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = fruit.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = fruit.description
    // add code to download the image from fruit.imageURL
    return cell
  }
  ```

---

Edit:

In Swift 4 everything became much shorter and more convenient. The most significant change is to drop `SwiftyJSON` and use `Decodable`

```
struct Fruit : Decodable {
   let name : String
   let imageURL : URL
   let description : String
}

func parseFruits() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"jsonFile", withExtension: "json")!
    let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOfURL: url)
    self.fruits = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Fruit].self, from: jsonData)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One additional question. In my application if I want to see the result from your function I have to prepare it for segue and send it to my TableViewCell.swift
Whhat exactly should I prepare for segue from your answer here?

Comment: I updated my code with the Table View Cell variables.Basically I hope you can understand me I have to prepare for segue your final function and = to each of ma variable in Table View Cell ( CellDescription, CellImage and CellTitle)

Comment: would you please help me how to do it ?

Comment: I don't understand. If the table view cell belongs to the table view in `TableViewController` you don't need a segue but subclassing the cell in Interface Builder. Anyway the code to download the image asynchronously is beyond the question, look at the [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) by Apple

Comment: Hey It works now, but what should I add in the comment line:  // add code to download the image from fruit.imageURL

Comment: I wrote this:  let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL:(string: fruit.imageURL))!)
        cell.CellImage.image = image

Comment: You should download the data asynchronously to avoid to block the UI what the synchronous `contentsOfURL` actually does. As mentioned before this is beyond the question. Look at the sample code I linked to.

Comment: This Answer Helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have got the Json Data,  Just need to put it in an array and load them into table view like this:

```
    var tableData:NSArray = []

    self.tableData = json["fruits"] as! NSArray
    // In the place of json put your json object
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.tableData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let item = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as! [String : String]
    cell.nameLabel?.text = item["Name"]
    cell.descriptionLabel?.text = item["Description"]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This it will Help you

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        var dict = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl1.text = dict["Name"] as? String
        cell.lbl2.text = dict["ad_created_date"] as? String
        cell.lbl3.text = dict["phone_number"] as? String
        cell.lbl4.text = dict["id"] as? String
        cell.lbl5.text = dict["ad_zip"] as? String

        let imageUrlString = dict["Picture"]
        let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: imageUrlString as! String)!
        let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!
        cell.img.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)



        return cell
    }
```